# Error in deleting an expression in a sentence using replace - Java

Tags: java, regex, netbeans

I am actually trying to delete the following expression:

> ??  ur  [Ljava.lang.String;??V?? {G   xp    t ?

from the following sentence:

> ?? ur [Ljava.lang.String;??V??{G  xp   t ?/store/sd/Android/data/map/files/exApp

I am using this Java code in order to proceed so:

```
 public String convertByteToString(byte[] bytes){

     String str=new String(bytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     String newstr=str.replace("[Ljava.lang.String;??V??{G  xp   t ?);
     return newstr;
 }
```

However, it gives me the following result:

> ?? ur[Ljava.lang.String;??V??{G xp t ?}/store/sd/Android/data/map
>       /files/exApp

Which is not correct at all because the expression has actually not been deleted as I wanted.

The weirdest thing is that when I am copying-pasting the string output from my NetBeans console to Notepad++, I obtain:

[image]

Do I have to include all these symbols in my Java code ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: https://ideone.com/6uqQQa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the 1st string is not in the 2nd, take a look at the image below..

you have a weird sign in the 2nd String

Just paste those in some TextEditor like Notepadd++ so you can identify it...

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer ! Actually, I am reading a MySql database Blob entry which contains a Ljava.lang.String. I have just updated my inital post in order to take into account this situation

Comment: check the format you are saving the string, UTF-8 missing?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 as the string format when I'm reading the Blob. I've added it to the post update.